# Finding patterns in numbers while parsing Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, numbers

If I have a list of numbers like
     112536
     523534
     241255
     233345
     212121
in a text file.

And I want to find any number where a digit is repeated three times in a row or a 2-digit set is repeated three times in a row, how would I do that?

The dumb way to do it is something like

```
while (line = f.gets)
   g.puts line if line =~ /111/
   g.puts line if line =~ /222/
   g.puts line if line =~ /333/  
   etc...
```

But that's obviously not efficient. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Try the pattern:

```
(\d)\1\1
```

which repeats a single digit 3 times and:

```
(\d\d)\1\1
```

will repeat two digits 3 times. Combining them would look like:

```
(\d\d?)\1\1
```

A rubular demo: http://rubular.com/r/J8VQ3SSGnT

The parenthesis around the `\d\d?` will save that single- or double digit in match group 1, and then that group is repeated twice (`\1\1`).

Comment: Great, thanks! From that, I already figured out the second example, which is (\d\d)\1\1

Comment: You forgot the `|(\d\d)\2\2` part.

Comment: And if I want to find 223322, I can with (\d)\1(\d)\2(\d)\1

Comment: @mu, ah, yeah, missed that part. Thanks. I shortened it a little though: `(\d\d?)\1\1`

Comment: @Magnus, yeah you seem to get the hang of it. Good!